# Не работает валидатор Asp.net

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net

Делаю проверку, заполнено ли поле или нет. И в том и другом случае браузер выдаёт такую ошибку -

> WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).

Не могу понять в чём проблема. У меня есть проект (взятый из лекции на курсе), в котором точно такой же код, но он работает. А мой, написанный ручками нет. Что делать?
Куда добавить этот ScriptResourceMapping?

```
<div>
    Логин
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
        ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
        runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
        ErrorMessage="Это поле не может быть пустым!"
        ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="OK" OnClick="OkButton_Click" />
    </div>
```

codebehind:

```
 protected void OkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            Response.Write("Операция прошла успешно");
        }
    }
```

Comment: пробовали [гуглить](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660900/webforms-unobtrusivevalidationmode-requires-a-scriptresourcemapping-for-jquery) ошибку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно было ввести в начале кода: UnobtrusiveValidationMode="None"

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" UnobtrusiveValidationMode="None" %>
```

И всё заработало. Больше информации по этой ошибке здесь - [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16660900/13326324)